# Bond Duration with Bond portfolio returns

Tags: fixed-income, bond, duration

if I have given CRSP bond portfolio returns with different maturities (1m-12m, etc), how is it possible to compute the Future price and the duration? 
Beside that I do also have the Nelson-svensson-siegel yield curve in form of zero coupon, par yield, instantaneous forward rate etc.

Thank you very much for any help!

Best,

Wende

Comment: What do you mean by "Future price"? Concerning duration: are you given the coupons and maturity?

Comment: I want to obtain synthetic future prices which can be replicated by zero coupon rates, I guess. The maturity is one year and the coupons are not given directly. Maybe it can be approximated by the par yield of the NSS yield curve?